# Playing remote videos in WatchKit Extension with WKInterfaceMovie

Tags: ios, swift, url, video, watchkit

I'm trying to play a video on the apple watch using *WKInterfaceMovie*. I want it to be a video on a remote server.

In a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448350/playing-videos-in-watchkit-app/34636070) a solution is given and I was able to reproduce this for local files. It's also said in the solution, that it only works for local files and I'm wondering why that is.
Are there any sources in the documentation or is it the general experience?

I was beginning to wonder, because it is said in the transition guide under **The Movie Object (WKInterfaceMovie)** that:

"The URL you specify for your media assets may refer to a local file or an asset located on a remote server. For remote assets, the movie object downloads the movie completely before playing it."

So I think it should be possible by that documentation even though I wasn't be able to implement it successfully, yet.

Comment: I answered a similar question here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/35167019/5039257](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35167019/5039257).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the loading circle and then nothing happens. Could you provide a link to a working video so I can be sure it's not about the link I'm using?